# How to use Backslash in a value of a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, backslash

I am using a below code and getting the results mentioned. My question is I need to use a single backslash in my value of a json object. Please help how to use it.

```
var text = 'jeep\\sand';
console.log(text) //returns  jeep\sand
```

```
let js = { "key" : text }
console.log(js) //returns {key:"jeep\\sand"}
```

My expected output in the second console is `{key:"jeep\sand"}` instead of the one I am getting now.

Comment: `console.log({key: "jeep\\sand"}.key)` will print `jeep\sand`. Maybe just use it that way. I didn't know about the strange behavior of `JSON.stringify()` either.

Comment: I don't want a string from a json object. I need json object itself

Comment: May I ask why do you need to remove that backslash?

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony What do you mean by "[the] JSON object itself"? `JSON.stringify` returns a string and the string it returns is correct. You already have the object (`js`). What other artifact do you need?

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton _ Ignore the JSON.stringify. I want the JSON to be contain '\' in its one of the value.

Comment: It does; I don't understand the issue. You're printing two different things: a string, and an object, rendered however the runtime renders an object. This one does more of an "inspect string" when the string is contained in an object. If you `console.log(js.key)` you see the console's rendering of a string again.

Answer (score 2):

For just printing it out, you can do like this:

```js
let json = JSON.stringify({ key: "jeep\\sand"});
json = json.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
console.log(json); // output: {"key":"jeep\sand"}
```

But note that the variable `json` no longer contains valid JSON.
`JSON.parse(json)` would throw an error now for example.

In JSON single backslashes has to be escaped and therefore must be represented by two backslashes. If you want to print out just one backslash, just use the object parsed from the json like this:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ key: "jeep\\sand"})).key);
```

If you want to print out whole objects, you can use an own function as follows:

```js
json = JSON.stringify({ key: "jeep\\sand", secondKey: "lambo\\water" });
console.log(json); // output: {"key":"jeep\\sand","secondKey":"lambo\\water"}
obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printObject(o) {
  let oString = "{ ";
  for (let key in o) {
    oString += `${key}: ${o[key]}, `;
  }
  oString = oString.substring(0, oString.length - 2); // remove trailing comma
  oString += " }";
  console.log(oString); // output: { key: jeep\sand, secondKey: lambo\water }
}

printObject(obj);
```

You can of course add " around the keys and the values if you want that to be printed. Just change `` oString += `${key}: ${o[key]}, `; `` to `` oString += `"${key}": "${o[key]}", `; ``

Comment: Hi @kzi Thank you for the answers but my requirement is to pass a JSON object which contains the value as '\'. So I definitely need to have a variable with type Object which include '\' in its one of the key. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony Be careful not to get confused with the terminology. JSON is text, i.e. a character string. An JavaScript object is an object in JavaScript, holding key-value pairs. So there is no such thing as a JSON object. And in a JSON string you will never find single backslashes.

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony I just edited my answer to include how you can print out whole objects. Maybe that's what you're searching for.